# Catch errors in destroy_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following action:

```
# DELETE /my_controller/ids[]
def destroy_multiple
  ids = params[:ids]

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    begin          
      SomeModel.where(id: ids).destroy_all
      head :no_content
    end
rescue => e
  p "e #{e.inspect}" # Never called
end
```

As you may have noticed, it's responsible for deleting many records, and it works...

*some_model.rb*:

```
before_destroy :check_default_item

private

def check_default_item
  return unless default_item?

  errors.add(:base, 'Cannot delete record because it is a default item')
  p "errors #{errors.inspect}" # I can see the errors
  throw(:abort)
end
```

Supposing that I have the following records:

```
[
  { id: 1, default_item: true },
  { id: 2, default_item: true },
  { id: 3, default_item: true }
]
```

If I send a request like this:

```
my_url/destroy_multiple?ids[]=3&ids[]=2&ids[]=1
```

I can see the errors in terminal, like this:

```
errors #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fdb88364050 @base=#<SomeModel id: 3, default_item: true, created_at: "2017-08-06 18:33:03", updated_at: "2017-08-06 18:33:03">, @messages={:base=>["Cannot delete record because it is a default item"]}, @details={:base=>[{:error=>"Cannot delete record because it is a default item"}]}>
```

**... but it gives me a 204 response, instead of a 422.**

Since I'm calling `throw(:abort)`, why doesn't it throw an error/exception? It didn't even go to `rescue`.

Note that if I try to delete a single record like this:

```
@item.destroy!
```

It works and I receive the "Cannot delete record because it is a default item" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`destroy_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all) method just loops through and calls `destroy` on each record, not `destroy!`:

> ```
> def destroy_all
>   records.each(&:destroy).tap { reset }
> end
> ```

The [`destroy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy) just returns `false` if it fails (from your `throw(:abort)`:

> If the before_destroy callback throws :abort the action is cancelled and destroy returns false.

This means if you're wanting an error to be raised (as happens when you use [`destroy!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy-21)), you'll need to use a custom method (there is no `destroy_all!`).

Since the body of `destroy_all` is relatively straightforward you could just replicate it in your code:

```
SomeModel.where(id: ids).each(&:destroy!)
```

should do it, if you aren't trying to reuse the relation for anything (and thus don't need it `reset`).